# Copy/Paste on another sheet excluding blank cells or cells where a formula result = ""

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

The code below is working as designed, with one exception:

Range b4:b100 are lookup formulas from another sheet where everything below B34 is a #value! error where I'm specifying =iferror(formula),""

It is copying the resulting "" and so the next time I it runs, it begins to paste on the target sheet on B101 rather than B35.

How can I specify "Do not use any space on the target sheet with blanks where formulas existed on the source sheet"?

```
Sub COPYTOSAVEDWORK()

Sheets("FORMULAWORKED").Range("B4:Q100").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("WORKED_CLAIMS").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1). _
  PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
  SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Value transfer instead of copy/pastespecial should get around this.

Comment: I agree @BigBen, however OP wants to paste values and formats. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @JvdV - you could value transfer, and then paste just formats, at least that's what I was thinking.

Comment: Ah, very true. You should post an answer @BigBen. I'll upvote

Comment: @JvdV - in case OP just wants the number formats and not everything else (since you can only paste all formats), I think the revised answer would be to value transfer the pasted range onto itself, that will eliminate the blank string.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.Value` = `.Value` on the pasted range, and that will eliminate cells with the empty string:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim formulaRng As Range
    Set formulaRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORMULAWORKED").Range("B4:Q100")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WORKED_CLAIMS")

        Dim nextRow As Long
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        formulaRng.Copy
        .Cells(nextRow, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        With .Cells(nextRow, "A").Resize(formulaRng.Rows.Count, formulaRng.Columns.Count)
            .Value = .Value
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ben, I was rethinking this, and I do think OP might have `""` values within the range of `B4:B100`. And he wants to avoid copying over those rows too.

Comment: @JvdV I assumed those rows are just at the end. So calling `.Value` = `.Value` after pasting would get rid of them. Could be wrong. If that weren't the case, I'd probably just filter and copy visible cells.

Answer (score 0):

A value transfer as per @BigBen would work great, but you seem to want to copy/paste numbers and `NumberFormat`. Maybe something like the below would work:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheets("FORMULAWORKED")
    .Range(Join(Filter(.[TRANSPOSE(IF(B4:B100<>"","B"&ROW(B4:B100)&":Q"&ROW(B4:B100),"|"))], "|", False), ",")).Copy
    Sheets("WORKED_CLAIMS").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi JvdV!  Thank you!  This begins to copy on column B of the destination sheet (Worked_Claims), but I was hoping that it would transfer the info to column A on the destination.  What is the tweak?

Comment: Ah right, I understand the problem however I can't get behind a pc for a while. The issue is we currently just copy whole rows.

Comment: @RobO, I believe I just fixed your issue. All rows in your range holding `""` in column B will now **NOT** be copied. The rest will get copied. Sorry for a rather late response.